# How can I add my custom keys to keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, windows-phone-8

Just like ".com" key is available in mobile IE and "@" in email fields, in my application I would like to add some custom keys to standard keyboard, namely "~" and "!". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. However you can change the input scope on your textboxes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929%28v=vs.95%29.aspx